# Comment prononcer "graphie naturelle" en poésie?

Tags: prononciation, poésie

Je crois qu'en poésie, le *e* doit se prononcer lorsqu'il est suivi d'une consonne donc ici on aurait gra/phi/e/na/tu/rell(e) mais ce découpage sonne étrangement pour moi.

De plus le site https://www.scribblab.com/outils/syllaber découpe en seulement six pieds la /gra/phie/na/tu/rell(e).

Quelle est la prononciation correcte?

Comment: 'graphie' se prononce toujours en deux syllabes /grafi/ quel que soit l'environnement

Comment: Est-ce une exception ou y a-t-il une règle sous jacente? Dans ce dernier cas, quelle est-elle? (Soit dit en passant, on prononce \ɡʁa.fi\ me semble-t-il)

Comment: Ce n'est pas exception. *Graphie* peut se prononcer comme "gras-fille", mais en poésie classique un mot comme *graphie* aurait peu de chance d'apparaître ailleurs qu'à la fin d'un vers (rime féminine), comme dans *Allons enfants de la patr**ie*** (comme "patrille").

Answer (score 3):

Tout dépend du mètre : on ne peut pas dire que « graphie naturelle » a une prononciation particulière dans n'importe quel contexte.

La règle ne dit ni « toujours le prononcer » ni « ne jamais le prononcer ». Elle dit plutôt :

- Si le mètre exige un pied qui n'est pas fourni par les autres syllabes selon leur prononciation habituelle,
- choisir un [e caduc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc) et le prononcer.

Par exemple, prenons les deux premières strophes du poème « [Le misanthrope philinte](https://www.poemes.co/le-misanthrope-philinte.html) » de Molière :

> Mon Dieu ! des mœurs du temps mettons-nous moins en peine
>
> Et faisons un peu grâce à la nature humaine
>
> Ne l'examinons point dans la grande rigueur,
>
> Et voyons ses défauts avec quelque douceur.

Si on en compte les syllabes on trouvera qu'il y en a 12 dans chaque vers : il s'agit de l'hexamètre. Sauf le troisième vers où il n'y en a que 11 !

[image: syllabes]

On doit donc trouver une autre syllabe pour complémenter ce vers. On la demandera de « grande » dont le e caduc se prononcera.

Par contre on laissera muet le dernier e de « peine » dans le premier vers car on n'en a pas besoin.

Il en est de même pour « graphie naturelle ». On doit savoir de quel vers la phrase est tirée.

Comment: Il me semble que dans le 3e vers, on prononcerait naturellement "gran-de ri-gueur" ? Et qu'on aurait écrit "grand' rigueur" pour omettre le e à l'oral.

Comment: @Sacha Naturellement, si, pour un-e francophone bien habitué-e à lire la poésie et qui suit sans devoir réfléchir la règle dont je parle. Mais dans le discours de tous les jours on ne met qu'une syllabe à "grande".

Comment: Je ne parle en effet uniquement de poésie.
Je n'avais jamais entendu parler de cette règle, j'aurais eu tendance à faire la démarche inverse (à la place de l'auteur), c'est-à-dire prononcer le e par défaut, et chercher à l'enlever si le vers contient une syllabe en trop.

Comment: @Sacha Pour moi il faut commencer par la prononciation habituelle si on veut parler de l'ajout ou de l'enlèvement d'une syllabe. Oui ou non, tu prononces « grande » avec une seule syllabe dans la vie de tous les jours ? La plupart des gens le prononcent [/ɡʁɑ̃d/](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grande#Prononciation), alors, si on parle d'enlever un schwa /ə/ final, c'est qu'on prend pour acquise une prononciation poétique. Dans ce cas on pourrait certainement parler plutôt de la suppression d'un e caduc, mais ce n'est pas le point de vue de cette répónse.