# "Embellie, divertie, de tes ..." combien de syllabes ?

Tags: poésie

Voila je m'adresse à tout ceux qui s'y connaissent dans le domaine de la poésie.
Récemment je me suis mis à composer un poème qui m'est cher et je suis face à un problème concernant ce "e" muet. Voici la phrase :

> Embellie, divertie, de tes feux d'artifice

Ma question est la suivante :

Est-ce que le *e* muet de « Embellie » se compte comme une syllabe puisqu'il est suivi de la consonne *d* de « divertie » ? De même pour le *e* muet de « divertie », compte-t-il comme une syllabe puisque il y a une consonne *d* de « de » qui suit ?

Y a-t-il donc 8 syllabes ? Ou bien 6 syllabes ?

Est-ce que la règle s'applique donc aux *e* muets précédés d'une voyelle telle que le *i* ?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44723/comment-prononcer-graphie-naturelle-en-po%c3%a9sie/44733#44733

Comment: Je crois qu'un "e" muet après un voyelle ne compte pas comme une syllabe depuis le seizième siècle.

Comment: J'ai réussi à trouver la réponse après de longues recherches, et vous venez de confirmer ce que j'ai lu. Merci.

Answer (score 1):

La règle générale en français est que le "e" muet à la fin d'un mot ne compte pas comme une syllabe, mais lorsqu'il est suivi d'une consonne, il peut former une syllabe avec cette consonne. Cependant, il y a quelques exceptions et des variations en fonction du style poétique.

Dans la phrase que vous avez donnée : "Embellie, divertie, de tes feux d'artifice," on peut analyser la répartition des syllabes comme suit :

Em-be-llie (3 syllabes)
di-ver-tie (3 syllabes)
de (1 syllabe)
tes (1 syllabe)
feux (1 syllabe)
d'ar-ti-fi-ce (3 syllabes)

Donc, en suivant cette analyse, il y aurait un total de **12 syllabes** dans votre phrase.

Comment: Vous vouliez dire "lorsqu'il est précédé d'une consonne", je suppose.